# Removing a section of the stud 17" long on a load bearing wall

Tags: walls

I am trying to install an in wall speaker. The problem I ran into was exactly where the cut out is going to be there is a pipe to the left "steam heating pipe". Then a beam to  right of it.

**Option 1** - The only direction I can go is to cut the beam side. I need to cut about 1 1/2 inches into the beam which is basically the beam size. It's only one beam, I am pretty sure its a load bearing wall. Will cutting that beam by 2"section by 17" long be a bad idea? I am not looking to take down a whole wall, just one beam. Will I need to support that beam with cripple stud, header, and jack studs? Will I need to add king studs?

**Option 2** - I move the speaker over another 20 inches "Kinda Far off" but again I am running into two beams and between the 20 inch mark, I would have to cut about 3/4 into both beams on each side and 17 inches the long way (top to bottom). Would cutting 3/4 of an inch off the beam be a bad idea or would I have to support it before I make the 3/4 inch cut, then support it afterwards with two 2x4's or a cripple stud horizontally then a king stud, header and jack stud?

Which option would be the easiest and safest way?

Comment: Is this in a fully detached house or in an apartment? Is the wall already opened up so you can see all these structural elements? Where is this?

Comment: Is it possible to do in ceiling speakers instead?

Comment: You use the term "beam" but reading your question it seams you mean stud not beam??

Comment: Thanks for your response :o Yes, fully detached home. wall is closed up. It's what i ran into while making the cut outs. Also ceiling speakers cannot give the same affect as "Front Left-Center-Front right" Speaker Can. The sound of these speakers come at you, not from above you. so ceiling speakers are not an option :o/ .  also you guys are correct i meant Stud, not beam.

Comment: Option 2, why 20 inches? Why not 6, 10, 11??? Is 20 a magic number? I would suggest that if you plan tjis, cutting into the stud for some unknown reason, that yes you install another stud next to it. I wouldn't go through more trouble that just installing the stud. This will throw off your 16"oc for that section of the wall. Now if there is something on the other side of this stud you want to cut, wiring, plumbing, etc, then you have another issue.